Biggest and Baddest: King Cobra
A program on snakes in India has this title in capitals.
Biggest and Baddest: King Cobra Biggest and baddest (see: 1:41-1:43)
Why "Baddest" instead of "Worst"? Is it simply to rhyme "Baddest"?

On the rhyming question, you are right that baddest was selected for its literary effect. But it's not rhyming, it's alliteration: the use of words with common first letters.

"Big bad X" is a traditional name for a fairytale villain, as in "Big Bad Wolf". The writer has jokingly used the incorrect superlative 'baddest' to reflect this.

@KateBunting, Thanks for the contribution. Taught me another aspect of reflection of culture on language.

Baddest is commonly used to mean the opposite of worst, as defined in sense 15 in Collins Dictionary and illustrated:

... slang
good; excellent


I'm one of the baddest, hardest-hitting heavyweights in the business.
Times, Sunday Times (2016)

In the cobra example, it has a similar sense as the heavyweights example in terms of size and power.

Baddest  expresses awe and respect for someone or something it's best not to tangle with.   It is colloquial.

The Great White is respected as the biggest and baddest of all the sharks, but the tiger shark is no slouch.
Dez Demonick is the meanest, baddest wrestler in the Women's Pro Wrestling Federation. Her last six opponents were carried out on stretchers.

